# Email client that restricts certain accounts to particular connection types, e.g. company WiFi at work, 3G/GPRS for personal

Tags: wi-fi, email, 3g, data-connection

Is there such an email account whereby in the account settings, one can choose which connection types that the account can use?

Would like this feature so that checking personal email goes through mobile/3G but does not go through e.g Wifi company workplace network or public Cafe Wifi, for privacy reasons.

It would be useful if one or more connection types or WiFi accesspoints could be specified for an account, e.g. if at home using home wifi - this would be allowed for personal.

Another option would be to have different email clients for different purposes but that might not be as manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question - I don't think there is such an email client yet that provides the facility to choose which internet connection(s) is/are used with each account.

Thanks for the DroidWall mention @FoleyIsGood, but I would prefer not to have to root my device for risks of malware, also because I use some backing apps which will not run on rooted devices.

Answer (score 3):

If you have root access then you could use [DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&feature=search_result) to give different apps, including email clients, access to WIFI and or mobile data. This would require you to use a different client for each account and wouldn't automatically differentiate between WIFI at work or at home. :o/

(It's a pretty rough work around but the best I could think of...)

Comment: thanks. I'd prefer not to root, I'll have a look around myself.